# Saving automatically to a second table in Phoenix Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a table called Requests, with fields Updated_by, Status, Notes, Start Date, File Number, etc. I am wanting to keep track of the history of the request, and have created a table called Encounters, which belongs_to Requests, and has fields Updated_by, Status and Notes.

I have it so that you can add encounters and show them on the Request page. What I am wanting to do is to automatically save to the Encounters table every time that a Request is created or edited. I am struggling with how the two Changesets can live together.

The following is the Request Controller

```
  alias Id.AccessId
  alias Id.AccessId.{Request, Encounter}

  def create(conn, %{"client_id" => client_id, "request" => request_params}) do
    client = AccessId.get_client!(client_id, conn.private[:subdomain])

    case AccessId.create_request(client, request_params) do
      {:ok, request} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Request created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.client_request_path(conn, :show, client, request))

      {:error, _changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, "Issue creating request.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.client_request_path(conn, :new, client))
    end
  end
```

Here is the create function in the Context

```
@doc """
  Creates a request.

  ## Examples

      iex> create_request(%{field: value})
      {:ok, %Request{}}

      iex> create_request(%{field: bad_value})
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}

  """
  def create_request(%Client{} = client, attrs \\ %{}) do
    client
    |> Request.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end
```

And finally the Encounter schema

```
 defmodule Id.AccessId.Encounter do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Id.AccessId.Request

  schema "encounters" do
    field :application_status, :string
    field :notes, :string
    field :updated_by, :string
    belongs_to :request, Request

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(encounter, attrs) do
    encounter
    |> cast(attrs, [:updated_by, :application_status, :notes])
    |> validate_required([:application_status, :notes])
  end
end
```

I have managed to create a form on the Show page to add to the table, but cannot figure out how do do it programmatically using Ecto/Changesets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) [natively supports](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-associations-embeds-and-on-replace) associations via [`Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) and [`Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4).

Somewhat like below would work.

```rb
%Request{}
|> Ecto.Changeset.change(...)
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:encounters, [%Encounter{status: "foo"}])
|> Repo.update!()
```

Comment: I am getting an error 
`function Ecto.put_assoc/3 is undefined or private`

Here is the code I have: 

`  def create_request(%Client{} = client, attrs \\ %{}) do
    client
    |> Ecto.build_assoc(:requests)
    |> Request.changeset(attrs)
    |> Ecto.put_assoc(:encounters, [%Encounter{application_status: "Beginning", updated_by: "Fred", notes: "Something or other"}])
    |> Repo.insert()
  end`

Comment: It is defined in `Ecto.Changeset` module, as clearly stated in both docs and my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a firm grasp of Ecto.Changeset, and have read the documentation, but am non able to get to to work. More literal instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “I am not able to get to to work” hardly explains where exactly you got stuck, what error have you got back etc. Adding `put_assoc(:encounters, [Encounter.changeset(attrs))` into the pipeline in `create_request/2` after `Request.changeset/2` should work.